# How to correctly format function calls in emacs

Tags: emacs, formatting

Does anybody know how to remove unwanted whitespace between function parameters.

for example I have a badly formatted function

```
foo ( int a , int b );
```

and I would like to get

```
foo (int a, int b);
```

I am looking for somethink similar to clean-ups or colon and brace hanging in CC mode. Ideally the correction is done when typing or pressing tab.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are lots of ways to accomplish what you are trying to do in Emacs. What have *you* tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using `query-replace-regexp`:

<kbd>M-C-S 5</kbd>`( +`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`(`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

<kbd>M-C-S 5</kbd>`+,`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`,`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

<kbd>M-C-S 5</kbd>`+)`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`)`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>